# My IBM quantum account has been disabled

Tags: ibm-q-experience

[image]

As shown in the picture above, my IBMQ account is unavailable, and I found that my friend's account is also unavailable, but I have not received any email or message notification. what happened?

Comment: In fact, mine too.

Comment: hmm.. interesting. I was wondering if it was just some maintenance related issue because  I just logged in mine just fine.

Comment: I still can't log in after 24 hours. I suspect that the account of mainland Chinese people has been banned, but even so, there should be a notice. For example, login is prohibited according to relevant regulations.

Comment: Have you tried to ask this through the Qiskit's slack channel? https://qiskit.slack.com/  That is very interesting if that is the case.

Comment: @KAJ226 Thank you! I will try it.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem - though from the UK not China. I was running a lot of code on the quantum experience site and I've got a feeling they kicked me for that. Did any find a reason why their account was disabled, and if it's possible to reactivate it again?

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem. Actually I have just registered my IBM account today, and I have not even signed in my IBM Quantum account to run the code. It makes no sense if my account is banned for violation of the Code of Conduct since I haven't had a chance to use it.

Comment: Thank you for your concern about this issue. I didn't get back my original account in the end, but I asked a friend for an MIT Edu mail account to register for IBMQ, and I still use it very well.

Comment: I'm closing this question because it is an issue specific to IBMQ account management

Answer (score 1):

IBM usually disables an account if their is a violation of the Code of Conduct. It can be an error, but is mostly accurate. Read [here](https://www.ibm.com/legal). I hope by now your account would have been recovered and every thing will be good.